# Accessing properties of elements that are not visible in design view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am learning ASP .NET with C# and I've run into a bit of a situation. I am working with Visual Studio 2013. Typically, to get into the properties of an element (a text box, a label, an image, a button, etc.), I go into design view and right click the entity I want to edit the properties of, and select properties.

On my current project, the element I'm trying to edit the properties of has been covered up by other content (due to this content being moved with CSS after the page loads). Is there a back door into the properties of elements on the page without design view, or a way I can get to it with out tearing my whole page apart?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: I thought that too; however, I'd seen on other posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to the element in HTML, placing the cursor in the element's code, and then going into design view will show the properties menu on the left side like it's been selected.